# notifyItemRemoved() en Recyclerview con Cursor

Tags: android, recyclerview

Buenas, tengo un RecyclerView con su correspondiente  clase adaptador que extiende de lo siguiente: `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuariosAdaptador.MyViewHolder>`

A ese adaptador le paso un Cursor y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Yo cuando poblaba un RecyclerView con un ArrayList por ejemplo, si quería borrar un elemento y darle un efecto a través del metodo `rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());` utilizaba el siguiente código en mi adaptador :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//delete es una ImageView
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lista.remove(position); //Lista es un ArrayList

            notifyItemRemoved(position);

            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,getItemCount());
        }
    });
}
```

Bueno pues eso me funciona perfectamente, pero el problema viene cuando quiero hacer eso mismo con un Cursor, que claro, a un Cursor no se le pueden borrar tuplas (que yo sepa).

¿Cómo tendría que hacerlo? ¿Volviendo a hacer una consulta a la BD, haciendole seguidamente un `swapcursor()` y indicándole la posición donde estaba el campo que he borrado?